# Searching in a Bitonic Array becomes infinite loop

Tags: java, search

I am trying to write a searching algorithm in a bitonic array. Please take a look in the ascending function, where I am printing 'lo'. When I run this code, it keeps print that 'lo' number. I don't understand why it becomes infinite loop there. Here is my code:

```
public class bitonicArray {

    public int ascending(int[] a, int key, int lo, int hi) {
        int mid = lo+(hi-lo)/2;
        while(lo<=hi) {
            if (key<a[mid]) hi = mid-1;
            else if (key>a[mid]) {
                lo=mid+1;
                System.out.println(lo);
            }
            else return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int descending(int[] a, int key, int lo, int hi) {
        int mid=lo+(hi-lo)/2;
        while(lo<=hi) {
            if(key<a[mid]) lo = mid+1;
            else if(key>a[mid]) {
                hi = mid-1;
            }
            else return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int bitonicPoint(int[] a) {
        int hi = a.length-1;
        int lo = 0;
        int mid = (hi-lo)/2;
        while(mid<=hi) {
            if (a[mid-1] < a[mid] && a[mid+1]>a[mid]) mid = mid + 1;
            else if (a[mid-1] > a[mid] && a[mid+1]<a[mid]) mid = mid - 1;
            else if (a[mid-1]<a[mid] && a[mid+1]<a[mid]) return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int ind(int[] a, int key) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length-1;
        int bit = bitonicPoint(a);
        int asc = ascending(a, key, lo, bit-1);
        System.out.println(asc);
        int desc = descending(a, key, bit+1, hi);
        if (asc != -1) {
            System.out.println(asc);
            return asc;
        }
        else if (desc != -1) return desc;
        else return bit;        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n[]= {1,3,4,6,9,14,11,7,2,-4,-9};
        bitonicArray ba = new bitonicArray();
        System.out.println(ba.ind(n, 6));   
    }
}
```

Please help with this. I am pretty new in Java. I am a Python user. Trying to learn Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of code fragment you are not updating your `mid` value

```
public int ascending(int[] a, int key, int lo, int hi) {
    int mid = lo+(hi-lo)/2;
    while(lo<=hi) {
        if (key<a[mid]) hi = mid-1;
        else if (key>a[mid]) {
            lo=mid+1;
            System.out.println(lo);
        }
        else return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Initially when this function is called from `ind` function , value of `lo` is 0 and `hi` is 4.
So, mid value is 2. 
Because of this in `while` loop it goes in this part :

```
 else if (key>a[mid]) {
            lo=mid+1;
            System.out.println(lo);
 }
```

Hence you get your first `lo` value printed , but then you have updated `lo` value but not 
`mid`.
Because of which every time `mid` is at 2 and in while loop each time it goes in same code fragment. You need to update value of `mid` because it is dependent on `lo` and `hi` and in the above `else if` part you have updated value of `lo`.

Corrected code is :

```
public int ascending(int[] a, int key, int lo, int hi) {
    int mid = 0;
    while(lo<=hi) {
        mid = lo+(hi-lo)/2;
        if (key<a[mid]) hi = mid-1;
        else if (key>a[mid]) {
            lo=mid+1;
            System.out.println(lo);
        }
        else return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```